# How to limit number of permutations

Tags: python-3.x, permutation

I have about 20 short strings that I want to permutate. I want only permutations that have `len == 8`.

I would like to avoid calculating *every* possible permutation, as seen below:

```
import itertools
p = itertools.permutations([s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6,...])
for i in p:
    s = ''.join(j for j in i)
    if len(s)==8:
        print(s)
```

But that's too slow right? How can I decrease the number of calculations? (to not spend processing and RAM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first, obvious thing to do is filter out any strings with length > 8:

```
newList = [i for i in [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, ...] if len(i) <= 8]
```

Then, you can use the second argument of `itertools.permutations` to set the number of items you want. If you have no empty strings in your list, you'll never need more than 8 items, so we can use 8 as the second argument:

```
p = itertools.permutations(newList, 8)
```

However, if any of your strings are *longer* than one character, this won't get you what you want, since it will only return permutations of exactly 8 items. One way to resolve this is to iterate through the various lengths:

```
pList = [itertools.permutations(newList, length) for length in range(1, 9)]
```

Yet here you end up with an enormous amount of permutations to filter through: P(20, 8) + P(20, 7) + ... P(20, 1) = roughly [5.5 billion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%2820+permute+x%29++1+to+8), which is impractical to work with.

### A different direction

Instead of using permutations, let's use combinations, of which there are far fewer ("only" [263,949](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%2820+choose+x%29++1+to+8)). Recall that in combinations, the order of the combined items doesn't matter, while in permutations it does. Thus we can use the smaller set of combinations to filter for the length 8 that we want:

```
cList = (combo for length in range(1, 9) 
    for combo in itertools.combinations(newList, length) 
    if len(''.join(combo)) == 8)
```

Using `()` instead of `[]` will make this a generator rather than a list, to delay evaluation until we really need it. And now we are close!

We can get our final result by taking the permutations of the items in `cList`:

```
result = [''.join(perm) for combo in cList 
    for perm in itertools.permutations(combo)]
```

Comment: but that gives me a string like s1s2s3s4s5 and that string not necessarily has len 8

Comment: Ah I see. Well you can use the same for loop you already have, but start with the permutation length 8 I'm suggesting here instead of permutations of any length. That would cut out a lot of computation.

Comment: No it doesn't. Sorry but what do you mean 'have to stick with some version of what you already have'?

Comment: @larissa: you have about 20 short strings.  You permutate all of them.  For each permutation, you concatenate all the strings in the sequence.  Assuming  each string is of non-zero length, how do you ever expect len(s) == 8? It will always be at least 20.. so you need to use the length argument to limit the number of strings in each sequence to something that will (occasionally) produce a concatenated string of length 8.  Excessive use of RAM should not be a concern here because `permutations` is a Python **generator**, which means it creates one permutation at a time, not all of them at once.

Comment: I'm making a wordlist creator to improve my string skills, I wanted to permutate combinations of the strings that gives me a 8 len string, but sounds like would take much much time to compute. Thanks for the RAM info!

Comment: For the sake of argument, let's say that your word list consists of words that are between 3 and 5 letters in length, inclusive.  If you perform all permutations of 20 such words, taken 2 at a time, that's only 380 permutations total.  Furthermore, your filter will print just the ones that choose 3+5 and 4+4 letter words.  I think you will find the execution time rather fast.

Comment: How can i automate this word choice based on size?

Comment: @larissa I've rewritten my answer to better solve your problem